# Airport for Yellowstone and Grand Teton national parks?

Tags: airports, yellowstone, grand-teton

My girlfriend and I are planning to go to Yellowstone and Grand Teton National Parks and had a few questions if anyone can help us!

What's the best place to fly (from Boston) into, if we want to minimize both flight price and driving distance to Yellowstone? I heard someone say that it's best to fly into Salt Lake City, as both flights and car rentals will be cheaper. Here's a quick breakdown of a few options we're considering, all based on the same travel dates and from the airport to the center of Yellowstone:

- Salt Lake City: ~$500, 5 hour drive, ~$300 car rental
- Billings: ~$500, 3 hour drive, ~$200 car rental
- Cody: ~$600, 2 hour drive, ~$600 car rental
- Bozeman: ~$500, 2 hour drive, ~$650 car rental

...so it really seems like Billings is the obvious choice. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Where are you flying from?

Comment: @MichaelHampton, ah, thanks, I should have mentioned that. I'm flying from Boston.

Comment: Be sure to also search for flights to/from MHT, as you may find some deals you wouldn't otherwise have.

Comment: @YungHummmma I trimmed your question down considerably. Our format here is best suited to handle one objectively answerable question at a time; you had too many questions, and too many of those other questions were opinion-based. If you disagree with the edit, you can always roll it back; however, do take the [site tour](http://travel.stackexchange.com/tour) and review the [help center](http://travel.stackexchange.com/help) first.

Comment: Have you looked at Jackson Hole?  It sits on the southern border of Grand Tetons.

Comment: How (after choster's edits) is this question too broad? It is a very simple question: "What's the best place to fly (from Boston) into, if we want to minimize both flight price and driving distance to Yellowstone?" Obviously there may be a tradeoff where one has the best price and another has the best drive but that doesn't mean the question is too broad. Can someone who voted to close explain themselves?

Answer (score 2):

[Wikvoyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Yellowstone_National_Park) also lists Jackson Hole (JAC), West Yellowstone (WYS) and Idaho Falls (IDA) as possibilities.

I don't know your exact dates, so I can't tell you how much the flights will cost.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll check those out. I didn't put the exact dates (we actually haven't decided, but know within a few weeks' tolerance) because I assumed the flights from different places would scale pretty similarly with time.

Comment: @YungHummmma Jackson Hole and West Yellowstone are definitely closest. I know Jackson Hole has scheduled service (had a very nice lunch there once, watching the aircraft come and go) and a rather spectacular approach (flown it in a simulator). Idaho Falls is close and no doubt cheaper, has a good selection of rental car companies, and hotels in the city as well (there are hotels in Jackson Hole too, good and cheaper alternative to renting in the parks), didn't see any hotels in West Yellowstone, but we weren't looking and may have missed them.